# Best & fast approach to do AES 256 encryption/decryption in java web application

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, aes

I'm building spring cloud-based microservices application and I want to do field level database encryption at the application level to secure user private data like emails, names, addresses, etc. I did some research and found that application-level encryption/decryption is more secure than database-level encryption. for that, I have decided to use AES 256 bit encryption to secure my database. now I was confused about which java code to use there are so many examples available on the internet.

**here are my questions:**

1. which library to use?

- pure java based library.
- Java Native Interface (Cross Platform AES 256 GCM).

2. which library provides me faster encryption/decryption capabilities?

if pure java which library or code to use and if JNI than which library.

I hosted my application Linux server.

Comment: Try it yourself by creating a benchmark and see how well each method performs.

Comment: I don't hink that there are so many different Java code samples how to use AES. If you don't think so please provide sample links. Using AES in Java is straightforward, especially as you already know what cipher mode you want to use: `Cipher.getInstance(..)`. The only part may differ a bit is the key generation/derivation. That is the part where speed does not matter but a well designed encryption system. Especially when talking about a database.